# Random nextInt() as a For loop statement produces half the expected random value

Tags: java, random

Including nextInt() as a statement in a For loop produces different results than assigning a random value to a variable.
Example:

```
Random randomWorker = new Random();
int temp = randomWorker.nextInt((120)+1);
for(int i=0; i<temp; i++){
... //I create a list in this loop
}
System.out.println(createdList.length());
```

This will work and produce a list of expected random length - from 1 to 120 values. However, the following code does not:

```
Random randomWorker = new Random();
for(int i=0; i<randomWorker.nextInt((120)+1); i++){
... //I create a list in this loop, identical code as in the example above
}
System.out.println(createdList.length());
```

Repeated a hundred million times, several times, the maximum number of values saved was 62.

What is the reason for this difference?

Comment: The second loop will compare `i` to a _newly generated random number_ each time, not the same one.

Comment: The second loop will execute `randomWorker.nextInt((120)+1)` every iteration to check if it should continue. The chance of always hitting a value higher than the current iteration 120 times is just much smaller than the chance of the nextInt returning 120 when it is executed a single time

Comment: Tip: set a seed when you create a Random if you want to easily track what is happening in java (e.g. `Random randomWalker = new Random(3)`). Then, later you can remove the seed.

Comment: 'The expected random value' is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @user207421 by "expected" I meant that the number of values, after repeating the process a hundred million times, should sometimes be close to the upper bound.

Comment: @Sweeper OK, so it loops several times, and then randoms a value lower than the current i value, and breaks the loop?

Comment: Yes. That random value is on average 60.5, so `i` rarely goes over 60. The number of iterations probably follows some sort of distribution, but I don't know enough maths to tell you what it is (maybe binomial?).

Comment: @Sweeper That makes sense. Do you mind writing an answer? I'll accept it.

Comment: If I had known more about the maths behind this, I would have posted an answer, but I think for now I think max kremsner's answer covers my points quite well already.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your problem correctly but let me try and help you out anyway.

```
for(int i=0; i<randomWorker.nextInt((120)+1); i++){
  ... //I create a list in this loop, identical code as in the example above
}
```

In here you are calling another random integer.

Try the following:

```
Random randomWorker = new Random();
int temp = randomWorker.nextInt((120)+1);
for(int i=0; i<temp; i++){
... //I create a list in this loop
}
System.out.println(createdList.length());

Random randomWorker = new Random();
for(int i=0; i<**temp**; i++){
... //I create a list in this loop, identical code as in the example above
}
System.out.println(createdList.length());
```

Try using temp as an upper boundary rather than generating another random integer value for every single time the loop executes.
(using random as upper boundary will change the boundary throughout the iteration as it will call a new random integer every single time the loop starts again)

Answer (score 0):

Looks at this!

```java
for(A; B; C) { }
```

in your example:

- `A -> int i=0` expression will be executed before the first iteration *(i.e. **once**)*
- `B -> i<randomWorker.nextInt((120)+1)` and `C -> i++` expressions will be executed **after each iterations** *(i.e. **multiple times**)*.

That's why the first code snippet is fine, but the second is not.

```java
for(int i = 0, total = new Random().nextInt(121); i < total; i++){
    // ...
}
```

Comment: So, basically, the loop loops a few times, and then randoms a value lower than the current iteration count, breaking the loop. If you include that bit in your answer, I'll accept it as complete.